# Measurable function such that $f(af(x))$ is not measurable for any $a\ne0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I know there exist (Lebesgue) measurable functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f\circ f$ is non-measurable ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483761/self-composition-measurable) can be found an example).

Moreover, on can adapt this construction to find, for any $a\ne0$, a measurable function $f_a:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f_a(a\cdot f_a(x))$ is non-measurable.

My question is,

IS there a (Lebesgue) measurable function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that for any $a\ne 0$ the function $f(af(x))$ is non-measurable?

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I would be very surprised if such a function did not exist. Pretty much any class of functions that mathematicians regularly deal with are a tiny well-behaved island in a vast sea of malignancy.

Comment: I also think so, but I wonder if an explicit example can be obtained